# What happens in java when a thread gets suspended in the middle of invoking a method on a field while another thread changes the field?

Tags: java, concurrency

I was reading Java Concurrency In Practice, and saw a program like this:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TestImmutable {

    private volatile OneValueCache cache =
            new OneValueCache(new BigInteger("1"), new BigInteger[]{new BigInteger("1")});

    public void service(int sec) {
        Random random = new Random();
        BigInteger i = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(random.nextInt()));
        BigInteger[] factors = cache.getFactors(i, sec);
        if (factors == null) {
            factors = new BigInteger[]{i};
            cache = new OneValueCache(i, factors);
            System.out.println("After update: " + cache);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestImmutable testImmutable = new TestImmutable();
        new Thread(() -> testImmutable.service(0)).start();
        new Thread(() -> testImmutable.service(15)).start();
    }

}


class OneValueCache {
    private final BigInteger lastNumber;
    private final BigInteger[] lastFactors;

    public OneValueCache(BigInteger i,
                         BigInteger[] factors) {
        lastNumber = i;
        lastFactors = Arrays.copyOf(factors, factors.length);
    }

    public BigInteger[] getFactors(BigInteger i, int sec) {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(sec);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Inside cache: " + this);
        if (lastNumber == null || !lastNumber.equals(i))
            return null;
        else
            return Arrays.copyOf(lastFactors, lastFactors.length);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OneValueCache{" +
                "lastNumber=" + lastNumber +
                ", lastFactors=" + Arrays.toString(lastFactors) +
                '}';
    }
}
```

It says in the book because class `OneValueCache` is immutable, so its usage in `TestImmutable` is thread safe.

However I'm curious about what happens if one thread gets suspended when **in the middle of executing** `cache.getFactors(...)` and then another thread updates the `cache` reference, then the first thread continues to execute the code. In this case which object is the first thread is working with, object before or after the second thread updated?

The code above was intended to create a scenario like this, but i can't control when and where the thread gets suspended, so I don't think its working right.

Comment: By the way: neither thread even needs to be suspended for a potential problem to occur, since almost all modern systems have multiple cores, code on multiple threads can *actually* run in parallel (as opposed to timesliced on single-core systems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...invoking a method on a field...

You don't invoke methods on fields. You invoke methods on *objects.* When you write `cache.getFactors(i,sec)`, that's invoking the `getFactors` method on the *object* to which `cache` refers. Let's call that object, *O<sub>1</sub>*, and let's call that invocation of the `getFactors` method, *Call<sub>1</sub>*.

If some other thread subsequently sets `cache=new OneValueCache(i,factors)`, then `cache` now refers to a different object, *O<sub>2</sub>*. But, that doesn't change which object was the target of *Call<sub>1</sub>*. If that function invocation still is in progress, then it still is working on *O<sub>1</sub>*. When *Call<sub>1</sub>* accesses `lastFactors` or `lastNumber`, it still is accessing the fields of the *O<sub>1</sub>* object.

It's still true even when the other thread subsequently invokes `cache.getFactors(i,sec)`. That's *Call<sub>2</sub>* which is working on *O<sub>2</sub>*. But, *Call<sub>1</sub>* doesn't know anything about that. It will continue to work on *O<sub>1</sub>* until it returns.

Answer (score 1):

Since `OneValueCache` itself is thread-safe, there's really only two possible results when calling `cache.getFactors()` while another thread is potentially changing `cache`:

- either the thread read `cache` from memory "before" the other thread updates it and it gets the old value *or*
- the thread reads `cache` from memory "after" the other thread updates it and it gets the new value.

But since `cache` is never assigned `null` and all instances of `OneValueCache` behave correctly (an instance might not have cached the "desired" value, but if it doesn't it'll correctly return `null` which is handled correctly in `service()`) nothing will break: the code doesn't rely on `cache` having the same value more than once (which is a common source of race conditions), as it only reads it once.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I don't think I explained it well though, what confused me is that since `cache.getFactors()` is not atomic, what if a thread gets suspended when executing `cache.getFactors()`, like right after `lastNumber == null` in the method, then another thread changes the `cache` field, then the first one comes back to examine `!lastNumber.equals(i)`, in this moment which cache object is the first thread working with.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, and maybe *I haven't explained well*, because if `cache` changes at any time during that call, it doesn't matter: a single thread will always *either* see *only* the old value or *only* the new value. Since `cache` isn't read from more than once, there's no risk of it being inconsistent. Your code might be doing "unnecessary work" (if multiple threads try to create a cache for the same values at the same time and overwrite each others work), but it won't ever produce incorrect results. "atomic" only matters when you do multiple operations on mutable state.

Comment: @Unicorn you don’t access the `cache` variable inside the `getFactors()` method; you use a predefined symbol named `this` which contains a copy of the reference used for the invocation. The reference stored in `this` does never change during the invocation. As said by Joachim Sauer, the `cache` variable is read once for the invocation and that read operation *is* atomic.

Comment: If what Holger describes is the source of the confusion, then the answer by Solomon Slow might shed some light onto the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that if one thread updates `cache`, while another is reading it, the second thread will either see a reference to the old or new instance of `OneValueCache` (this is guaranteed by the volatile variable). And because `OneValueCache` is immutable, is not that the values could change under the rug.

There could be one problem though. Imagine that service calls `getFactors` twice.

```
    public void service(int sec) {
        BigInteger[] one = cache.getFactors(i, sec);
        [...]
        BigInteger[] two = cache.getFactors(i, sec);
    }
```

In this case the underlying cached value could have changed. If that's a bad thing, the code could first assign `cache` to a local variable and reference that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what confused me is that isn't `cache.getFactors()` **not atomic**. what happens if a thread was in the middle of executing `getFactors()` and gets suspended, then another thread changes the`cache` field, then the first thread comes back continue to execute `getFactors()`, then will this be a problem?